# insert part of file name into (first) column of csv

Tags: excel, csv

I have hundreds of csv files with filenames in the following format: yyyymmdd_something.csv, e.g. 20131213_something.csv ... i.e., an underscore separates the date from the rest of the filename.

Each of has the following fields:
Make, Model, metric 1, metric 2, etc.

I would like to:

1) Insert the date from the file name into (preferably first) column, like so:

Date, Make, Model, metric 1, metric 2, etc.

But really it can be any column because once in Excel, it is a simple matter to re-arrange it. The date should be added as mm/dd/yyyy as it is what Excel understands.

2) After inserting the date, I would like to merge all the csv into 1 big csv file.

I'm using a Win7 machine so a dos batch file would probably be the simplest way to run it for me but if I had to, I can install perl or something to do this. Any help would be deeply appreciated. There was a thread that talks about inserting the whole file name but I really need only the date part added.

Comment: Does an individual **.csv** have lots of records or only a single record??

Comment: each csv has a lot of records, usually >100.

Answer (score 1):

Hi this can be done by vbscript, the code is below:

Create a VBS file (notepad can do it, just paste following code and save file as .vbs)

You can drop 20-50 files (yyyymmdd_something.csv) as the same time to the icon of this vbs file and it will process as you wish :)

Please create Summary.csv file first and update its full path to **pSumaryCSV** = "......\Summary.csv"

```vb
'USAGE: 
'CREATE A VBSCRIPT FILE .VBS WITH THIS CONTENT
'CREATE SUMMARY CSV FILE AND UPDATE ITS FULL PATH IN pSumaryCSV
'DRAG AND DROP YOUR ORIGINAL CSV FILE TO THIS VBS FILE ICON, IT CAN PROCESS MULTIPLE FILE (BUT DON'T PUT TOO MANY AS ONE)
'THIS CODE WILL CREATE A NEW CSV FILE <ORIGINAL FILE NAME>_DATE_ADDED.csv
'AND UPDATE Summary.csv file.


Set objArgs = WScript.Arguments

Set objFso = createobject("scripting.filesystemobject")

dim objOrgFile
dim arrStr ' an array to hold the text content
dim sLine  ' holding text to write to new file

'Location of the summary file - Full path. If it is not exist then create it first. 
'The summary one should have all column lable since following code will not add label to it.
pSumaryCSV = "......\Summary.csv"

'Open the summary file to append data
    set aSummaryFile = objFso.OpenTextFile(pSumaryCSV, 8) '2=Open for writing 8 for appending


'Looping through all dropped file
For t = 0 to objArgs.Count - 1
    ' Input Path
    inPath = objFso.GetFile(wscript.arguments.item(t))
    inName = objFso.GetFileName(inPath)

    ' OutPut Path
    outPath = replace(inPath, objFso.GetFileName(inPath), left(inName, InStrRev(objFso.GetFileName(inPath),".") - 1) & "_DATE_ADDED.csv")

    ' The original file
    set objOrgFile = objFso.OpenTextFile(inPath)


    'Now Creating the file can overwrite exiting file with same name
    set aNewFile = objFso.CreateTextFile(outPath, True) 
    aNewFile.Close  


    'Open the new file (...._DATE_ADDED.csv) to appending data
    set aNewFile = objFso.OpenTextFile(outPath, 8) '2=Open for writing 8 for appending



    '=======================================================================
    'Process first line, this firstline will not be added to SummaryCSV File
    If Not objOrgFile.AtEndOfStream Then
    arrStr = split(objOrgFile.ReadLine,",")
    sLine = "Date,"             'This will add Date label for

    For i=lbound(arrStr) to ubound(arrStr)
            sLine = sLine + arrStr(i) + ","
        Next

    'Writing first line to new file but not the summary one.
        aNewFile.WriteLine left(sLine, len(sLine)-1) 'Get rid of that extra comma from the loop
    end if

    '=======================================================================

    ' Reading subsequent line and writing it to new file
    Do Until objOrgFile.AtEndOfStream
        arrStr = split(objOrgFile.ReadLine,",")

    'Get the mm/dd/yyyy path from file name yyyymmdd
    sLine = ""
    sLine = sLine + Mid(inName,5,2) + "/"   'Get mm from file name
    sLine = sLine + Mid(inName,7,2) + "/"   'Get dd from file name
    sLine = sLine + Mid(inName,1,4) + "/"   'Get yyyy from file name
    sLine = Sline + ","         'This will add a column 

        For i=lbound(arrStr) to ubound(arrStr)
            sLine = sLine + arrStr(i) + ","
        Next

        'Writing data to new file
        aNewFile.WriteLine left(sLine, len(sLine)-1) 'Get rid of that extra comma from the loop

    'Writing data to summary file
    aSummaryFile.WriteLine left(sLine, len(sLine)-1)

    Loop

    'Closing new file
    aNewFile.Close  

Next ' This is for next file

'Close Summary File
aSummaryFile.Close

set aSummaryFile=nothing
set aNewFile=nothing
set objFso = nothing
set objArgs = nothing
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked! I edited the code to add a "/" in the sLine so that excel recognized the date. Excel doesn't recognized mmddyyyy, only mm/dd/yyyy. Thanks again.